# Prove $(1 - a)^n \geq 1 - na$ for $0 < a < 1$

Tags: induction

This is exercise problem from "The Art of Computer Programming - Fundamental Algorithm".

> Prove by induction that if $0 < a < 1$, then $(1 - a)^n \geq 1 - na$

Here is my attempt:

- If n = 1, then $1 - a \geq 1 - a$ is true.
- We may assume by induction that $(1 - a)^n \geq 1 - na$ holds, then $$(1 - a)^{2n} \geq (1 - na)^2 = 1 - 2na + n^2a^2\geq 1 -2na$$ so by induction, the property holds for any integer n.

---

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have written:

- if $n=0$, then $1 \geq 1$
- assume it holds for all $k \le n $, then we'll prove it for $n+1$
  $$(1 - a)^n \geq 1 - na$$
  $$(1-a)^{n+1} = (1 - a)^n \cdot (1-a) \geq (1 - na)(1 - a) = 1 - (n + 1)a + na^2 \geq 1-(n+1)a$$ so it holds for every $n \geq 0 \Rightarrow \forall  n \in \Bbb{N}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to Induction so please don't mind if my question is too easy for you guy.

Comment: you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your induction step goes from $n$ to $2n$, your proof only shows that the result holds for $n= 1,2,4,8,16,\dots$. Usually, you'll want to go from $n$ to $n + 1$ in the induction step: We'll then have something like

$$(1 - a)^{n + 1} = (1 - a)^n (1 - a) \ge (1 - na)(1 - a) = 1 - (n + 1)a + na^2$$

Comment: I know valuable lesson here. Thanks for your feedback.